# Why does the propagation delay need to be greater than the hold time when you have two D-FFs connected like this?

Tags: flipflop, stable

[image: circuit]

In the above circuit, why does the propagation time `Tp > Th`? As I understand it, once the first D-FF changes value, it will propagate that value to its output, that is the `Tp`. Then on the input side of a D-FF we have the `Th` which is the amount of time needed for the input to be stable *after* a clock edge (why must it be stable for that time after a clock edge???). What I don't understand is why the above stated relationship must hold?

Comment: OK, I think I understand where it comes from. It would be right if Tp is referring to some logic *between* the registers - which is not shown here. In that case, *after* the clock is changing, the input to the second register needs to be stable for at least `Th`. And the propagation delay of that logic will ensure that.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Sure, now we're back to my original question. I don't get this. Feel free to post a detailed answer if you will.

Comment: So let's assume `Tp` is referring to the propagation delay from `CLK` to `Q0`. It means that after the clock is changing, `Q0` will remain stable for at least `Tp`. `Th` is referring to the minimum time the signal needs to be stable in the input of the second register. So if `Tp > Th`, then it is satisfied. Otherwise it isn't

Comment: @EugeneSh. Ok I believe your answer makes sense. If `Tp` was to be less than `Th` then `Q0` could potentially end up unstable and as such when the second FF samples a new value, it'll potentially enter into a metastable state. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, sounds correct